# Numpy array manipulation- Adding and Subtracting work, but not multiplication and other methods

Tags: python, numpy

I'm creating a program that creates matrices based on user input and allowing them to choose from a menu a few different way to manipulate and change the matrices. I got adding and subtracting to work fine, but when I do multiplication it's giving me this error:

```
ValueError: shapes (3,1,3) and (3,1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 2) != 1 (dim 1)
```

And when I try to use `np.transpose()`, it gives me this error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U11'), dtype('<U11')) -> dtype('<U11')
```

``

```
def Matrices():
    menu=("Pleae enter an option from the menu below\n\n1.Addition\n2.Subtraction\n3.Multiplication\n4.Calculate row and column averages\n5.transpose\n6.Exit")
    user_input = 0
    print("Create first matrix")
    matrix1 = Create_Matrices()
    print("Create second matrix")
    matrix2 = Create_Matrices()
    while user_input!=4:
        user_input = int(input(menu+"\n"))
        if user_input == 1:
            C = matrix1+matrix2
            print(C)
        if user_input == 2:
            C = matrix1-matrix2
            print(C)
        if user_input == 3:
            C= matrix1.dot(matrix2)
            print(C) 
        if user_input == 4:
            C1_column = matrix1.mean(axis=0)
            C2_column = matrix2.mean(axis=0)
            print("The mean of matrix one's columns are ")
            print(C1_column)
            print("The mean of matrix two's columns are ")
            print(C2_column)
            C1_row = matrix1.mean(axis=1)
            print("The average of matrix one's rows are ")
            print(C1_row)
            C2_row = matrix2.mean(axis=1)
            print("The average of matrix two's rows are")
            print(C2_row)
            #print("The row averages for matrix 1 are: "+C1_row+"\nThe row averages for matrix 2 are: "+C2_row)
        if user_input == 5:
            matrix1 = np.transpose(matrix1)
            matrix2 = np.transpose(matrix2)
            print(matrix1+"\n"+matrix2)
        if user_input ==6:
            Exit()
```

``

Comment: '+' is elementwise addition. `*` is elementwise multiplication, obeying the same dimension (`broadcasting`) rules.  `dot` is matrix multiplication, with different rules (**read its docs**).

Comment: What are you trying to do with `5`?  `1` looks like numerical addition, but this one has a string.  For strings `+` is string join.  Did you even look at what `transpose` produces, and test whether tha makes a difference in that action?  When writing code, test problem pieces in an interactive session.

Answer (score 0):

```
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U11'), dtype('<U11')) -> dtype('<U11')
```

This error means that your array contains unicode fields. Make sure that your array contains only numbers.